In Ubuntu, After every minut CPU get 100% with some php process
I have a problem in my ubuntu installed laptop, after every 10 minutes, my CPU consumption reach to 100% with some unknown php process.



You have likely been hacked. Wipe your system and reinstall, and hope your backups are good.

The problem was my php cron was running every minute.I run
crontab -e

i changed  * * * * *
to   5:AM      0 5 * * *

